# Integrity constraint violation:1062 Duplicate entry after product import

Tags: magento2.2.6

I have imported some products into Magento 2.2.6. Everything looks correct in the backend but when I reindex I get this error-

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-510' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `temp_catalog_category_tree_index_40850d82` (`parent_id`,`child_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, 
Product Categories indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-510' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT  INTO `temp_catalog_category_tree_index_cebdbaaf` (`parent_id`,`child_id`) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, ?), (?, 
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

I can't find that table to remove duplicate so it must be pulling from another table. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause of the Issue:

data corruption

Investigation:

categories with IDs 510, 511 have incorrect path values:

```
mysql> select row_id, entity_id, path from catalog_category_entity where path like '1/1/%';

+--------+-----------+---------+
| row_id | entity_id | path    |
+--------+-----------+---------+
|    510 |       510 | 1/1/510 |
|    511 |       511 | 1/1/511 |
+--------+-----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
Resolution: not a bug
PLEASE PERFORM THE FOLLOWING ACTIONS:
execute the next SQL:
update catalog_category_entity set path = replace(path, '1/1/', '1/') 
where path like '1/1/%';
```